# How to avoid polygons getting "filled" while using rasterio and geopandas

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, shapely, rasterio

I have a numpy array that's filled with 0's and 1's.
I'm trying to convert the cells filled with 1's into polygons. To do this I'm using rasterio, shapely and geopandas.

```
def flooded_to_shapefile(array, transform, filename):

    shapes = rasterio.features.shapes(array, transform = transform)
    
    # Select only cells with 1's
    polygons = [shapely.geometry.Polygon(shape[0]["coordinates"][0]) 
                for shape in shapes if shape[1] == 1]
    
    # Create dataframe with polygons
    df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(polygons)
    df.columns = ["geometry"]
    df.set_geometry(col='geometry', inplace=True)
    df.to_file(filename)
```

The problem I'm having is that in the matrix I have holes that are not correctly represented in the final polgyons. For example, look at this:

In the colored representation of my matrix I have white areas that I want to polygonize
[Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0wJW.png)

When I run the my code I get the following.

[Resulting polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ28X.png)

As you can see, the star shape, for instance, is incorporated into the polygon, but since it contains 0 values it should not. The line shape[1] == 1 should be preventing the star getting selected (as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72202177/creating-polygons-using-rasterio-and-shapely-based-on-a-lon-lat-and-an-array-of), but the polygon still "closes". Do you have any idea of why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initializing the Polygon object uses 2 arguments, shell (the outer ring) and holes (the inner rings). You are only giving it the shell so you get a filled polygon.

I think you can give each `shape` (a geojson-like dict) in your rasterio `shapes` as argument to the shapely.geometry.shape function in order to get polygons with holes.

```
# Select only cells with 1's
polygons = [
    shapely.geometry.shape(shape[0]) 
    for shape in shapes if shape[1] == 1
]
```

should do the trick

Comment: Great, this makes the job. Make I ask where do I get info about the shape method, strangely I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#python-geo-interface, it is a little bit hidden.